# How to get the view slideshow option in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, picture-library, picture

In sharepoint 2010, when I made a picture library I had this option:

[image]

But in SharePoint 2013, I don't seem to have this option, how can I get to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slide libraries have been deprecated in SharePoint 2013.

Use this alternate way to get the slide libraries working in SP 2013
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/11/finding-missing-sharepoint-2013-slide.html

> The Slide Library is not listed as an "App" or displayed in the old
>   Create.aspx page (_layouts/create.aspx). But… you can still get it
>   with a direct URL. I would not depend on it being there forever as the
>   Slide Library is officially not in 2013, but for now you can create
>   one.
>
> The direct URL to create the old Slide Library:
>   http://yourserver/sites/yoursite/_layouts/15/slnew.aspx?FeatureId={0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d}&ListTemplate=2100

Comment: This creates a new app which probably works, but what if I have an existing picture library from a 2010 environment that was migrated. Is there a way to get the slide show view for that to work?

Comment: Correct in the case of slide libraries which are migrated from 2010 will not work in 2013 and currently there is no alternate available as per my knowledge.